# Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer

In my Puppeteer Node JS app I need to read localStorage and cookies from a browser web page, but for some reason I'm getting the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.

What am I doing wrong/missing from my JS:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const AdvancedFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat');
dayjs.extend(AdvancedFormat);

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { config } = require('./config');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const logs = require('./logs');

const runEmulation = async (body) => {
  logs.debug('starting emulation');

  // vars
  const argOptions = [], journey = [];

  // sandbox config
  if ((config.puppeteer.run_in_sandbox === 'true')) {
    argOptions.push('--no-sandbox');
  }

  // initiate a Puppeteer instance with options and launch
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: argOptions,
    headless: (config.puppeteer.run_in_headless === 'true') ? true : false
  });

  // launch a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  // initiate a new CDP session
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send('Network.enable');
  await client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', async (e) => {

    // if not a document, skip
    if (e.type !== "Document") return;

    const scrapablePageData = async () => {
      
      function getLocalStorage () {
        const values = [];
        const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
        let index = keys.length;

        while (index--) {
          values.push({
            key: keys[index],
            value: localStorage.getItem(keys[index])
          });
        }

        return values ? values : [];
      }

      return {
        localStorage: getLocalStorage()
      }

    }

    const scrapable = await page.evaluate(scrapablePageData);
    const cookies = await page.cookies();

    // the data we want to log
    journey.push({
      url: e.documentURL,
      type: e.redirectResponse ? e.redirectResponse.status : 'JS Redirection',
      storage: {
        cookies: cookies ?? [],
        local: scrapable.localStorage ?? []
      },
      duration_in_ms: 0,
      duration_in_sec: 0,
      loaded_at: dayjs().valueOf()
    })
  })

  // set userAgent and go to the URL
  await page.setUserAgent(body.userAgent);
  await page.goto(body.url);
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  console.log(journey)
}

exports.runEmulation = runEmulation
```

Comment: Same problem as your other post -- `await client.on` is wrong -- see the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession). These functions synchronously register handlers, not return promises, so there's nothing to `await` and you have a race condition. Showing a runnable, [mcve] with a sample website and clear desired result would help immeasurably in providing a working answer for you.

Comment: Okay, so I tried removing `await` from `client.on`, and unsurprisingly, I get the same error. Creating a reproduction would be difficult since you can't run Puppeteer in a web browser, the above is a Node script, so my best guidance would be to set up the above in a Node script and parse a URL such as https://example.com/ to the `goto`

Comment: I don't think I'm too far away from obtaining localStorage information from my attached code? What am I missing?

Comment: A MRE isn't about running it in a browser, it's about providing code I can copy-paste into my Node environment and hit "run" and see the problem. Here, there's all manner of helper/config files I don't have access to, dependencies probably irrelevant to the issue. The other point of a MRE is that it makes the question more relevant to future visitors with the same problem -- they've also stripped their problem down to its simplest form and can easily spot the same failing pattern in your code rather than having to sort through a bunch of noise to figure out whether it's even the same issue.

Comment: No, removing `await` doesn't fix the problem, it's just that it's a red herring possibly giving you a false feeling of ordering that doesn't exist. `waitForNavigation` seems misplaced -- that usually needs to be placed alongside an event that triggers navigation inside into a `Promise.all`.